# Best way to manage express server dependencies in production env

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, webpack, development-environment

I’ve developed an application with a react front end and a node server on the backend. The React dependencies are bundled by webpack into bundle.min.js, but when I put my server.js on a container/VM wherever, how do I ensure its dependences (i.e. express, winston, body-parser, etc) are installed.

npm install --production

will install my production dependences on the server but this will include everything from react, react-dom, d3, etc.

I have tried using a separate webpack configuration to make a server bundle, along the lines of,

```
{
    name: 'server',
    target: 'node',
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'server', 'app.js'),
    devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist', 'server'),
      filename: 'server.bundle.js'
    }
},
node: {
  __dirname: false
}
```

but when I start the server I am getting a `Cannot Get /` error.

#### What is the best method to install only the dependencies related to my express server for a production build?

Comment: If you are doing server side rendering you will need them, if your server is only serving an API, you can split the two apps.

Comment: @GabrielBleu Splitting into two apps seems like kind of a maintenance headache; I'd prefer to keep them as one so that I can just run `npm run build` and have everything and all necessary dependences ported to a _dist/_ directory. Is that not standard?

Comment: Also, I do plan to implement server side rendering in near future.

Comment: if you need/feel that they should separate just do it, two projects one for backend another for frontend, no matters at the end the webpack build will include those deps that you are calling on your frontend sources only (except of course that you are doing something terrible wrong)

Comment: You can put all your front dependencies as dev dependencies. The client bundle will still contains what it needs, and the `npm install --production` will only install server dependencies on the container.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are potentially going to run out of file space, I don't think its a problem to have all of your dependencies installed.  It certainly makes maintainability simpler vs creating two separate projects.  What advantage do you get from trying to only install production packages on your server?  Or better yet, what disadvantage is there to having all of them?